# Odd Java ternary behavior when assigning value. What is Java doing behind the scenes for this to happen?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-operator

A few days ago, I ran into a fascinating scenario that I couldn't find any documentation on how or why Java lets the following happen. (This snippet is just a simplified form of the bug.)

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
      boolean bool = false;
      Integer intVal = Integer.valueOf(5);
      Long longVal = null;
      Long result = bool ? intVal : longVal;

      System.out.println(" > " + result);
   }
```

in the snippet above:

if the bool = true, then you get the value '5';

but if bool = false, then you get a null pointer exception when trying to evaluate the ternary operation. NOT the print statement.

---

To fix this I just change 'result' to

```
Long result = bool ? Long.valueOf(intVal) : longVal;
```

Doing this, will give the expected behavior I needed:

if the bool = true, then you get the value '5';

but if bool = false, then you get 'null'

---

now the fun part is that if you split this into a normal if/else statement, then java does NOT let you compile

```
longVal = intVal;
```

but it doesnt catch that via the ternary operator. So what's Java doing to make it null point in the original snippet?

(java 11)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Long result = bool ? intVal : longVal
```

This expression is returning a `long` and, when `bool` is false it tries to unboxe `null` to a Long value to fit the `result` variable and throws a NPE.

When you do this:

```
Long result = bool ? Long.valueOf(intVal) : longVal
```

This expression is already returning `Long` then there is no need for unboxing and the `null` value is successfully assigned to the `result` variable.

**Reference:**

As discussed in the comments section, to better understand why does this happen, check the following sections of the JLS:

- [Section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2): Binary Numeric Promotion
- [Section 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25): Conditional Operator ? :

Comment: I'm surprised you different reference [table 15.25 A to E](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) where it is "clear" that Integer/Long result in a bnp(Integer, Long).

Comment: Good answer. Generally when I have absolutely no idea, whats going on inside, I recommend having a look in the compiled bytecode, which reveals almost exactly, what described. At least when extracting a minimal code snippet, that's more or less a matter of training, how to read and understand it.

Comment: As the [JLS, Section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) says: "If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion"; then "Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied [..]"